# Laravel Check Empty Array

Tags: php, laravel, is-empty

I still have trouble with checking if an array is empty or not in laravel.

This is my view:

```
@foreach($restaurantmenue as $daily)

                    @if(empty($daily->articles))
                      no article
                      @else
                        @foreach($daily->articles as $menue)
                            <a class="card-link" href="#">
                                <h4 class="title">{{$menue->title}} </h4>
                            </a>
                       @endforeach
                    @endif


                @endforeach
```

{{dd($daily->articles)}}
When I check my views (One with an Article and the other without an article)       I get this output:

The View with an existing article shows:
    Collection {#228 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▶]
    }

And the view without an article shows:
    Collection {#227 ▼
  #items: []
}

I have no idea why the code in the IF STATEMENT is not executed. The "No Article" Message is not displayed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because it's Laravel collection, you can use [`isEmpty()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-isempty) helper:

```
@if($daily->articles->isEmpty())
```

Comment: GREAT! THANK YOU Alexey, you helped me out again!