# Deeper understanding on Laravel Collection returns (newbie)

Tags: php, laravel

Why can't I use empty (`$example->body`), and need to use `$example->body->isEmpty()` to check for empty array. What is the return type that causes it can't use empty() and need to rely on `isEmpty()`?

I do know this is from Laravel Collection based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39346593/laravel-check-empty-array?newreg=5c46b8eb22a8450fb318a452694684bd). But didn't really understand why behind the scene. Any enlighten is greatly appreciated (but I'll try to understand it from freshgrad POV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`empty()` cannot work because it always returns true

> Because if you dd($example); you'll notice you'll notice an instance of Illuminate\Support\Collection is always returned, even when there are no results. Essentially what you're checking is $a = new stdClass; if ($a) { ... } which will always return true.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563166/eloquent-collection-counting-and-detect-empty)

Answer (score 1):

[PHP empty manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

> Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value.
>   Otherwise returns TRUE.

In the manual they provided things that are considered to be empty. `object` type is not part of it. Instance of Laravel collection (`Illuminate\Support\Collection`) is considered as a `object` type. It doesn't matter if the object is plain empty object for `PHP`, the `empty()` will always returns `false`

Comment: Thank you. I understand the PHP empty() return TRUE or FALSE flag depends on the empty. But I didn't grasp on why it's consider empty() FALSE. If it's consider as object, then it'll always return FALSE via empty().